# 'Bundle Exec Jekyll Build' not updating site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, windows-10, jekyll, static-site

I am working on a Windows 10 OS and I am using command line to push a Jekyll site to a personal server/domain. The jekyll files were originally complied on a Mac. I have adjusted the gems for windows.

My site works fine using 'bundle exec jekyll serve', but when I go to build the site, nothing changes.

Is there any idea what might be causing this issue?

I have attached two screencaps - one using the `bundle exec jekyll build --watch` command and the other simply `jekyll build`.

[image: bundle exec jekyll build --watch]

[image: only jekyll build]

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the documentation.

- `jekyll build` simply builds the site and puts it in **_site** folder.
- `jekyll build --watch` does the same, but also updates the content of the **_site** folder.

Both commands above just create your site. But to make it "live" you need a web server, which is provided by `jekyll serve` command:

> Jekyll also comes with a built-in development server that will allow you to preview what the generated site will look like in your browser locally.

`serve` works more or less as `build --watch` + provides server.

Comment: So when I do Jekyll serve, I need to have that going to our host provider?

Because I have also used 'jekyll serve', expect it only shows on the local server.